# What agency were Nick Fury and Agent Coulson working for in Captain Marvel?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

From the way Nick Fury and Agent Coulson were presented in *Captain Marvel*, it appears that S.H.I.E.L.D. hadn't been established yet. In fact, it was only until the end of the film that the concept of the Avengers was hinted at, as well as the necessity of creating an agency to track supernatural threats.

So, who were Fury and Coulson working for? Do they actually mention this at some point? Perhaps I'm just forgetting something from when they first introduced themselves to Vers at the Blockbuster...

Comment: Don't wanting to be rude but, have you seen the movie? Fury and Coulson work for S.H.I.E.L.D and it is mentioned throughout the movie, Fury even gives a S.H.I.E.L.D hat for Carol to wear. Clearly S.H.I.E.L.D exists before the Avengers initiative...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Yeah, I saw the first showing the day it came out. Like I said, I must have overlooked it. I just remember them talking about how they didn't believe the "alien" story that Vers pitched them until Fury saw it shape shift in the car when it died.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting negative votes. It's a genuine question. Just answer and move on. Thanks.

Comment: @Charles I think it's getting downvoted because S.H.I.E.L.D. is mentioned several times in the movie. Some people probably view this question as similar to, "What is Colonel Fury's first name? They might have mentioned it but I only heard Fury."

Comment: Ignoring "Captain Marvel", the opening scenes of "Ant-Man" show 1989, the Triskelion under construction and Hank Pym confronting the executive body of SHIELD (the logo is on the wall)

Comment: I downvoted following the reason when you hover the downvote button. "The question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful". A simple google search, and/or second viewing of the movie, or simply paying attention to the movie would answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clark Gregg, the actor who plays Coulson, refers to the organization as S.H.I.E.L.D.:

https://ew.com/movies/2018/09/13/clark-gregg-captain-marvel/

And from the film:

> Carol Danvers: [Referring to the front of the baseball cap that Fury
> has given her] What is this?
>
> Nick Fury: It's a S.H.I.E.L.D. logo.
>
> Carol Danvers: Does announcing your identity with branded clothing,
> help with the covert part of the job?
>
> Nick Fury: ...said the space
> soldier who's wearing a rubber suit. Lose the flannel.

and

> Nick Fury: We have no idea what other intergalactic threats are out
> there. And our one woman security force had a prior commitment on the
> other side of the universe. S.H.I.E.L.D. alone can't protect us. We
> need to find more.
>
> Agent Coulson: More weapons?
>
> Nick Fury: More heroes.
>
> Agent Coulson: You think you can find others like her?
>
> Nick Fury: We found her and we weren't even looking.